# How to import data form libsvm to R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I need to use data set (for example vowel testing and training data set ) from [libsvm website](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/)  to do classification using e1071. Then compare the performance of R with libsvm3-17. The problem is that I can not import the libsvm data to R that can be used by e1071. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read libsvm format with built-in methods in your R library

```
library(e1071)
read.matrix.csr(...)
```

or use code by `zygmuntz` from github:

https://github.com/zygmuntz/r-libsvm-format-read-write

Comment: Dear lejlot, Thanks for your reply actually I've tried read.matrix.csr with the following codes